# How to get semantic type of a word?

Tags: nlp, semantics, ontology, wordnet

I am working in NLP field and in my work, I need the semantic type of the words. I am wondering if there is any tool which does that for me.
I already know that there are `WordNet supersenses`, but that is not enough for me. I need something more fine-grained.

To better clarify what I need, I would say that I need ontological semantic types. For example, `WordNet supersenses` classes include `noun.artifact` which is very general and defined as `nouns denoting man-made objects`. So, it doesn't matter whether the artifact is a house or a brick!

Another example is adjectives that are categorized under one class called `adj.all` in `WordNet supersenses`. But I want to make a distinction between different types of adjectives. For example, adjectives of human being and adjectives that can't be used for humans.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It may help if you clarified what you mean by "semantic type". The first thing that came to my mind was truth-conditional semantics types, but then you mentionned WordNet, which makes it sound like what you are looking for is an upper ontology.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at resources such as [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu), or [FrameNet](http://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu)

> ConceptNet is a semantic network containing lots of things computers should know about the world, especially when understanding text written by people.
>
> The FrameNet corpus is a lexical database of English that is both human- and machine-readable, based on annotating examples of how words are used in actual texts.

Depending on what you want to achieve there are lots of resources that provide ways of accessing semantic, but interpretation maybe up to you and your learning technique.